# PHP MySQL date between

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

The system is for phone contract comparison. Originally we could filter the result by length, given in months. However we've opted to storing this as a `timestamp` of the *end date of contract* in the database.

The original PHP was as follows:

```
$min = min($_POST["length"])-6;
$max = max($_POST["length"]);
$query[] = "length BETWEEN $min AND $max";
```

In summary, here's what we have at the moment:

1. In the database is stored the end-date of the contract (as a timestamp)
2. The post value contains how many months from now it should last (eg. 7-12 months would have a value of 7)

**How can we change the PHP calculations to get the between values from the database?**

Many thanks, Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $diff = 7;     // This may be set to $_POST['length']
    $max = date("Y-m-d");
    $min = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$diff months ago"));
    $query[] = "DATE(`timestamp_field`) BETWEEN CAST($min AS DATE) AND CAST($max AS DATE)";
?>
```

Comment: Is it not essential to cast the $min and $max dates to ensure the correct data type? `DATE(timestamp_field) BETWEEN CAST($min AS DATE) AND CAST($max AS DATE)`

Comment: @Daniel I'm unsure of the `CAST` function- what does it do?

Comment: @Daniel Ah, yes. I normally keep my `date` and `time` type columns separate. So, this was prebuilt code. :)

Comment: @NickPrice; The CAST function makes sure that the value is of a certain data type. If you would compare $min $max without casting, the values would probably be treated as string, and not date. See link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast